# Sum mixed columns in MySql/Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql table that have some integer fields and some text fields. Inside text fields I have multiple numbers separated by comma.

What I need is to return the result by summing all the columns group by two particular keys. When summing, I want to sum up all the integer fields (which is straight forward) as well as all the text fields where each comma separated values should be summed up respectively.

I can't explain it more clearly without example, here is what I want

```
Table:
Key1    |Key 2  |Col1   |Col2   |Col3   |
A       |X      |2      |12     |2,4,6  |
A       |X      |4      |23     |3,6,9  |
A       |Y      |6      |54     |1,3,5  |
A       |Y      |8      |27     |4,8,12 |
B       |X      |1      |12     |5,10,5 |
B       |X      |3      |31     |6,3,1  |
B       |Y      |5      |23     |1,0,0  |
B       |Y      |7      |91     |2,5,6  |

Output I want:
Key1    |Key 2  |Col1   |Col2   |Col3   |
A       |X      |6      |35     |5,10,15|
A       |Y      |14     |81     |5,11,17|
B       |X      |4      |43     |11,13,6|
B       |Y      |12     |114    |3,5,6  |
```

I am using mysql and python to store the output to new table. For the integer fields, I easily use mysql SUM() function. For Col3, I use python map(add,a,b) function to individually add the the values.

The problem is, the code I am using looks ugly, and I think it'll be inefficient when I'll work with large amount of data. Any suggestion of doing this efficiently?

My current code stands:

```
cursor = cnx.cursor()
sqlout = "INSERT INTO tb2 (`key1`,`key2`,`col1`,`col2`) SELECT `key1`,`key2`,SUM(`col1`),SUM(`col2`) FROM tb1 GROUP BY `key1`,`key2`"
cursor.execute(sqlout)  // TESTED
cnx.commit()
sqlint = "SELECT `key1`,`key2`,`col3` FROM tb1"
cursor.execute(sqlint)
results = cursor.fetchall()
myres = {}
for row in results:
    myres[row[0],row[1]]= (map(add,myres[row[0],row[1]],row[2])
//USE MYSQL UPDATE COMMAND TO UPDATE tb2 from myres variable // NOT TESTED
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: May we see the code you consider ugly?

Comment: updated ... the last part I haven't tested as I have to loop through the dict myres and update tb1 (which I called ugly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Python at all, you can do it in plain MySQL. First, define some helpers:

```
create function column1(x text) returns integer deterministic
    return substring_index(x,',',1);

create function column2(x text) returns integer deterministic
    return substring_index(substring_index(x,',',-2),',',1);

create function column3(x text) returns integer deterministic
    return substring_index(substring_index(x,',',-1),',',1);
```

Then, here is the query:

```
select 
    Key1, Key2, 
    sum(Col1) as Col1,
    sum(Col2) as Col2, 
    concat_ws(',', 
        cast(sum(column1(Col3)) as char(50)),
        cast(sum(column2(Col3)) as char(50)),
        cast(sum(column3(Col3)) as char(50))
    ) as Col3
from YourTable
group by Key1, Key2;
```

Comment: thanks a lot .. i never used function in mysql before .. I'll check that .. one more question, is there any good way I can keep the number of columns as well as number of elements inside CSV string variable?